# data mismatch while using solr DIH

Tags: apache, tomcat, solr, solrj, solrcloud

I am trying to pull documents into solr from another solr using DIH.
solr A has 10k docs but when i pull data into solr B , solr B has only 9k.
Num Docs:9k , Max Doc:10k .i have attached my DIH xml below.`<dataConfig>
  <document>
    <entity name="files" processor="SolrEntityProcessor" url="http://x.x.x.x:8983/solr/test" query="*:*"/>
  </document>
</dataConfig>`

Comment: Differing maxDoc and numDocs are usually caused by duplicate ids / uniqueKey field entries, as the new document overwrites the old one.

Comment: issue was on our side.We had some duplicate records in our core.Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differing maxDocs and numDocs numbers after an import to a clean core or collection is usually caused by documents being overwritten - because of duplicate values in the `id` (or a different `uniqueKey` field if configured).